# How to find last day of specific month of specific year with strtotime() in php

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have month in number (i.e. 1,2,3...12)
I have year in number (2015,2014...2010)

What I try to do is that using strtotime() to find

```
strtotime("last day of 2 month 2021");
```

in this case, 2 and 2012 will be variable in a number listed in 1st and 2nd sentence.

I wonder is that possible to do? Because I tried the one I wrote here, its not getting the right date after I test the result of `$at = strtotime("last day of 2 month 2021");` with `$time = date('Y-m-d', $at);` it always seems sending me the date of the current year. in the above example, result of  `date('Y-m-d', $at);` will be

```
2015-04-30
```

what I expect to get is

```
2021-02-28
```

Anyone?

Comment: Do you mean what day is the last date?  Eg Mon,  Tues?

Comment: no, its more of the date like 2015-01-31

Comment: I rarely use strtotime. I get weird things out of it all the time. If you want the full date of the last day of the month, I would use: date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0, $month+1, -1, $year)); It will find the day -1 of the next month, which is the last day of the month you want.

Comment: Use `t` instead of `d` for the day for any date - like the 1st - in the given month and year: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @kainaw I tried your method, but seems that -1 put the day count one less, because I tried to do end of 2015 jan, it get 2015-01-30

Comment: @Chen You are correct. I was interrupted as I was typing and got confused. You want a 0 not a -1. Day 0 is the day before the first. Day -1 is the day before day 0. Sorry.

Comment: You can also use the function cal_days_in_month(); http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try DateTime object

```
 $date = new DateTime('2021-02');
 $date->modify('last day of this month');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Also, the last day of 2021 Feb is 28...

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy to find a leap year. Which really seems to be what you're trying to do.

```
if(2012%4 == 0)  {
    // it's a leap year
}
```